# MongoDB update operation inside multiple level of nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need help in updating the following collection.

```
{
    _id: "5983548781331adf45ec5"
    "name": "Company Name",
    "workspaces":[
        {
            _id: "7865548781331adf45ec5"
            "name": "workspace 1",
            "cards": [
                {
                    _id: "7865548781331adf478er",
                    "name": "card 1",
                    "panelId"; "1"
                },
                {
                    _id: "7865548781331adf4as34",
                    "name": "card 2",
                    "panelId"; "1"
                },
                {
                    _id: "7865548781331adf43548",
                    "name": "card 3",
                    "panelId"; "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: "we34548781331adf45ec5"
    ....
}
```

In the above collection I want to add a "card" with panelId=1 in the workspace only if it has less than 2 cards with panelId=1. In the above document I can't do the operation since it has two cards with panelId=1. I need to know how can I do this with a single query. I use nodejs & mongoose for this. I already know the document id and workspace id when i do the query.

Comment: You really cannot. You cannot match in multiple levels of arrays using multiple `$` operators. You should consider changing your schema if this is a common operation - perhaps making documents represent cards and denormalizing workspace ids into them?